# Unable to open DB file (code 14) Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, file

I'm using the SQLite DB on Android and I got that issue... I already put the permission "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and idk wtf I have to do! Plz, help me D:

Heres my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Livro> getLivrosWhere(String where) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = SystemDB.instance.open().db;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_FIELDS, where, null, null, null, "Ordem ASC");

    ArrayList<Livro> retorno = new ArrayList<Livro>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Livro livro = new Livro();
        livro.config(cursor);
        retorno.add(livro);
    }

    if (cursor.isLast())
        cursor.close();

    db.close();

    return retorno;
}
```

Broke when cursor.moveToNext()...

Comment: can you copy & past the whole log error ?

Comment: `I already put the permission "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` And **why** is it required?

Comment: Try initializing read from sdcard permission

Comment: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)

 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)

thats the error log

Comment: Idk Frank, i saw this in other answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SQLiteDatabase db = context.openOrCreateDatabase("sample.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```